# Does a Wizard's lightning hydra proc the paralysis passive?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-wizard

As per the title, does the Wizard's lightning hydra proc the passive to stun mobs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amongst other abilities, Hydra with the Lightning rune do not cause the Paralysis passive to proc. The abilities reported to be affected by this are:

- Storm armor's basic damage component
- Lightning Hydra
- Dartling

[Source](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5151717527), [second source](https://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5271777403?page=1).

Comment: Jeez, well that makes the Lightning Hydra utterly useless... thanks for the links.

Comment: @theorise Venom hydra :)

Comment: .. yup. I am currently using Arcane + Flux passive, just trying to see if any of the others are useful. So far, ice, mammoth and now lightning seem a waste of time in comparison to venom!

Comment: Arcane can shoot through walls... that is at least cool.  Flux adds a little value to that as well. However, the damage dealt by venom hydra, especially verse a stationary target is very strong.

Answer (score 2):

I can stun with my Hydra. I think it has changed in some recent patch, though I did not notice it in the patch notes or anywhere.

Comment: Hmm I will test this tonight.